# Order of the initialization in Java

Tags: java

I know, it's a very basic topic, so if it is a duplicate question, please provide a reference.

Say, there is a following code:

```
public class Point {

    int x = 42;
    int y = getX();

    int getX() { 
        return x; 
    }

    public static void main (String s[]) {
        Point p = new Point();
        System.out.println(p.x + "," + p.y);
    }
}
```

It outputs: `42,42`

But if we change the order of the appearance of the variables:

```
public class Point {

    int y = getX();
    int x = 42;

    int getX() { 
        return x; 
    }

    public static void main (String s[]) {
        Point p = new Point();
        System.out.println(p.x + "," + p.y);
    }
}
```

It outputs: `42,0`

I understand that in the second case the situation can be described as something like: "Okay, I don't know what the returned x value is, but there is some value". What I don't completely understand is how x may be seen here without being seen along with its value. Is it a question of compile time and run time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create an `int` in Java it is automatically initialized to `0`. So what the second code does is create two ints `x` and `y` set them both to `0` then set `y` to the value of `x` which is `0` then set x to the value `42`.

Answer (score 2):

`int` has 0 as a default value.

Answer (score 1):

So at compile time, the compiler is generating instructions to set aside space (memory) for x and y and to set their values to 0

At runtime, the JVM populates the Point object (assigns it memory) and assigns memory and  initial 0 values for x and y.

Then, the runtime initialization code starts executing and sets y to 0 and then x to 42 (in the second case)