# Why are non-static class variables initialiized at runtime and not compile time in Java

Tags: java, jvm

This is an extension of question: [Order of the initialization in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865044/order-of-the-initialization-in-java/)

so in the code block:

```
public class Point {

int y = getX();
int x = 42;

int getX() { 
    return x; 
}

public static void main (String s[]) {
    Point p = new Point();
    System.out.println(p.x + "," + p.y);
}
```

}

It outputs `42,0`

While the above question was answered by describing the behavior of the Java compiler and runtime, it is still bugging me why the compiler does not bake the initial value of x (42) into the bytecode?
I know the values of static variables get embedded into the bytecode since they are class level variables and they dont take up any space in the object memory, but doesn't it make sense to also embed any initial values for class level non-static variables also into the bytecode? That way, the code above will be more in-line with expected behavior, and the instantiation of the object will be quicker I am guessing (since the memory assigned to x will immediately contain 42 hence saving time in parsing the initialization line in the class every time an object of class Point is created)

I suspect this might have something to do with the tradeoffs between class bytecode size, object initialization efficiency, and compile time efficiency.

I am hoping someone with deep knowledge on Java compiler/runtime can throw some light on this.
Knowing how a framework works internally always helps us write better code :-)

Comment: Would it not create problems if the variable was an object? It's all fine and good when the value is 42 but what if the value is an object of class ComplexNumber? Do we want all our points to refer to the same memory address and, essentially, the same ComplexNumber? Now I am not someone with deep knowledge of Java compiler/runtime stuff so I could be totally wrong here but that's the best reason I can come up with.

Comment: It *does* 'bake the initial value of x (42) into the bytecode'. How do you think x ever gets to be 42? It doesn't bake it into the *instance memory,* because there *is no* instance memory, until you create an instance. At runtime. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a question of efficiency; it's a question of having sensible semantics.

The Java designers wanted the behavior of initialization to be the same whether `x` is defined to be `42` or to be `getFortyTwo()`, because if that behavior is *different*, then that leads to all kinds of ways to unintentionally shoot yourself in the foot.  So they specified in the JLS which order field initialization occurs in, and that order is *independent* of whether `x` is a constant or a method call or a potato.  (For reference, it's the order that you declare the fields in -- so if you reversed the order of `x` and `y` in your class, `y` would be set to 42.)

Frankly, I would bet that the compiler bakes the assignment `y = 0` into the constructor, because the JLS's semantics *require* that `y = 0` based on this code.

Comment: Interesting that we picked the same example of "weird behaviour if this were the case" :)

Comment: I'm not too surprised.  Library designers (a group that I think includes us both) tend to reflexively think in terms of "If this were different/the way you suggest, how could that come back to haunt you/cause unexpected behavior?"  The answer here is that anything that isn't an obvious constant could make the semantics confusing/unexpected -- and the best source of non-constants is method calls.

Answer (score 3):

> While the above question was answered by describing the behavior of the Java compiler and runtime, it is still bugging me why the compiler does not bake the initial value of x (42) into the bytecode?

Imagine if you later changed this:

```
int x = 42;
```

to this:

```
int x = getInitialValueForX();
```

Would you *really* want that to completely change the behaviour?

If `x` is *really* just a constant, then make it `static final` and it *will* be inlined. As it is, if a variable *isn't* final and *isn't* static then I don't see why it should be treated as a constant even though the initial value *happens* to be a constant at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are misunderstanding what happens with constants, and why.

Compile-time constants can be in-lined, but in general, static variables are not. A compile-time constant is [defined in the specification,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) but simply put, it's a value of primitive type that is known at compile time. There are many static variables that are initialized with expressions that aren't compile-time constants.

In this case, `Point` and `getX()` are not final, so the result of `getX()` is unknown at compile-time. How could it possibly be in-lined when a subclass could override it and return a different value?